# How should I add Include File to my Eclipse Project(Cpp, see image)

Tags: c++, include, eclipse-cdt

I remember somehow adding the include file, and then thought it would be automatic. It wasn't. So how do I add it again and make it automatic?

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "add and make automatic"?

Comment: I meant that add the include file as shown in the picture. By make at automatic, I meant so I don't need to manually add it every time I make a new project.

Comment: There is no include file in the picture.

Comment: I meant by "Include file" as the include under the file "Square String."

Comment: Ok! So the easiest fix is to not use eclipse for it. The even easier fix is to learn java..... which I am now currently doing